# What is the difference between various modes in FPE?

Tags: feistel-network, format-preserving

Format preserving encryption has three modes FE1( FFX) , FE2(VAES) , FE3(BPS) . All of them are based on Feistel Networks .Can somebody explain  how they differ from each other ?

Comment: It's even worse, FFX contains several different modes plus a bunch of parameters.

Comment: And further, FPE is far from limited to these modes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FF1, 2  and 3 are basically inspired by Luby-Rackoff constructions. At the core they differ in their round functions and key scheduling:

- FF1 supports greater range of lengths and a tweak;
- FF2 generates subkey for each iteration to thwart any side channel attacks;
- FF3 has tweaks is split and used in rounding function, also the reverse the sub-strings of given input string while using in round function.

Both FF1, FF2 have 10 rounds while FF3 has only 8 rounds.

There is more information in the [NIST's 800 38 G](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-38G) specification; note that FF2 has been withdrawn from it.

Comment: How do you decide which mode to use?

Comment: depends you need to pick on your requirements. you need greater range of lengths of formats or performance etc.

Comment: It would be nice to know also the patent constraint on using these. HP holds patent for FF1 sub-components. I guess the use in commercial software is somehow limited. I don't know how - contacting HP to learn more. Will let you know.

Comment: if you want a non-patented solution , check this https://github.com/cisco/libfnr , not a standard though , Disclaimer: am the co-author of this scheme